# Pop function for stack has unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was just taking lecture on behalf of my Guide and one student given this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stack{
     int top;
     int store[50];
};

void push(int num, struct stack stk)
{
        stk.store[stk.top] = num;
        stk.top = stk.top + 1;
}

int pop(struct stack stk)
{
        int temp = stk.store[stk.top];
        stk.store[stk.top - 1] = 0;
        stk.top = stk.top - 1;
        return temp;
}

int main()
{
        int i;
        struct stack imp, pl;
        imp.top = 0;
        for(i = 0; i<8; i++)
        {
                int choice, val;
                printf("Menu:\n\n");
                printf("1. Push\n");
                printf("2. Pop\n");
                printf("3. Exit\n\n");

                printf("Please enter the choice:");
                scanf("%d", &choice);
                switch(choice)
                {
                        case 1:
                                printf("Please enter the value to be inserted");
                                scanf("%d", &val);
                                push(val, imp);
                                printf("The position:%d\n",imp.top);
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                printf("The poped value is : %d at position:%d\n",pop(imp), imp.top);
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                return 0;
                                break;
                        default:
                                printf("Wrong choice.\n");
                }
        }
}
```

The value of top is always zero and pop is returning always zero.
Can somebody point out what is wrong with the code or the reason behind this behavior of the code.

Comment: Where is `struct stack` defined?

Comment: You need to pass the pointers. Period.

Comment: Debugger.....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [Stack implementation example](https://github.com/Mrunmoy/Stack)

Answer (score 2):

Your push operator assumes that `stk.top` is *one entry past* the top element of the stack. Your pop operator assumes that `stk.top` is *the top element itself*. (Sort of; it's actually a bit inconsistent internally.)

I suggest that you draw a diagram and run through some operations by hand, following the code line by line. Watch out for off-by-one problems and fix them as you find them.

[EDITED to add:] Oh, Sourav Ghosh (in comments to the original question) also makes a very important point: you're passing your stack object around by value rather than by pointer, which is also going to break everything -- because the modifications in the `store` and `pop` functions are applied to the copy, not to the original. I'm community-wiki-ing this answer since one of the key things in it is now from someone other than me.

Answer (score 2):

The pop function returns [top] but resets [top - 1] to 0.